# pandas: Divide DataFrame last row by first row

Tags: python, pandas

This questions is similar to [Python: Pandas Divide DataFrame by first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007406/python-pandas-divide-dataframe-by-first-row)

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
            1125400  5430095  1095751
2013-04-02    98.91      NaN  5626.79
2013-04-03    99.29      NaN  5727.53
2013-04-04    99.79      NaN  5643.75
2013-04-07   100.55      NaN  5630.78
2013-04-08   100.65      NaN  5633.77
```

I would like to divide the values of the last row by the values of the first row in order to obtain the percentage difference over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the first row and the last row values, then divide them, like this: `df.T[df.index[0]] / df.T[df.index[-1]]`

Comment: I used df.head() and df.tail() to get the first and last rows, and didn't realize they return DataFrames. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A clearer way is to use [iloc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[0] / df.iloc[-1]
```