# Divide first row by others, polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have the following polars dataframe

```
pl.DataFrame({'pme-site-paginas': [118,54,24,21,20,20,18],'pme-midias-novo-empresas':[348,149,67,50,47,46,39,],'pme-site-claro-mais':[8,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

So I have the following dataframe and I want to grab the first row and divide by the rest so I get the percentage considering the first value to be 100%.
Really similar to the following question in pandas, would appreciate some help on how I can do this?
[Divide DataFrame by first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007406/divide-dataframe-by-first-row)

Comment: It would help if you showed the expected output. It sounds like: `df.select(pl.all().first() / pl.all())`

Comment: @jqurious I think since they want a percentage, they *really* mean `df.select(pl.all() / pl.all().first())` but, of course, your way reflects what they actually said.

Comment: Your answer is actually the correct one I wish I could display the end result but you know lazyness